# MySQL DISTINCT function not working as I expected

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

Note: I am pretty new to MySQL so bear with me please.

I have 2 tables in my database which are set up as follows:

```
guides table:
guide_id (primary) | cat_id | title
   1                   0     guide01
   2                   0     guide02

steps table:
step_id | guide_id (foreign) | step_txt
   1              1            step1 text...
   2              1            step2 text...
```

And I am trying to search the database for keywords within steps.step_txt and return a list of guides. My current query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM guides 
    JOIN steps ON guides.guide_id=steps.guide_id 
  WHERE step_txt LIKE "%keyword%"
```

What I have found is that as some guides have more than one step with the keyword contained, this returns duplicated rows. I would like the query to output 1 row containing guide_id, cat_id and title even if it finds 2.

I think the problem is that I have used JOIN so the query is actually returning a joined row from both tables which would have different step_id and step_txt so the DISTINCT isn't effecting it. What is the best work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crude solution would be:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT guides.* 
  FROM guides 
    JOIN steps ON guides.guide_id=steps.guide_id 
  WHERE step_txt LIKE "%keyword%"
```

Possibly more elegant and giving you the matched text :-

```
SELECT g.guide_id, g.cat_id, g.title, GROUP_CONCAT(s.step_txt)
FROM guides g
INNER JOIN steps s
ON g.guide_id = s.guide_id 
WHERE step_txt LIKE "%keyword%"
GROUP BY g.guide_id, g.cat_id, g.title
```

Answer (score 0):

`distinct *` is going to return rows where *all* the columns are distinct.  For what you want, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM guides JOIN
     steps
     ON guides.guide_id = steps.guide_id 
WHERE step_txt LIKE "%keyword%"
GROUP BY guides.guide_id;
```

This uses a MySQL extension to `group by` and it will not work in other databases.  The columns returned from `steps` comes from arbitrary matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT guides.*
FROM guides, steps
WHERE step_txt LIKE "%keyword%" 
AND guides.guide_id=steps.guide_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IN operator

```
select guide_id from guides where guide_id IN (select guide_id from steps where step_txt LIKE "%keyword%")
```